# What does %(jscode)s in javascript mean?

Tags: javascript, syntax, google-visualization

The only use I can find for % in any javascript documentation is modulo division. I don't understand what this line of code does:

```
%(jscode)s
```

Source is line 13 of this:

https://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/gviz_api_lib.html#exampleusage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't actually Javascript, it's [Python string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

The file you link is a Python file and, when it's executed, additional Javascript code is inserted into it before it's sent to the browser.  `%(jscode)s` simply acts as the insertion point for that dynamic code.  You can see another insertion point — `%(json)s` — on line 18, the definition of `jscode` on line 46, and the actual formatting / interpolation on line 56.

Comment: Thanks, but why not just put the code there then?  Why even bother with the interpolation?  EDIT: Never mind, figured it out.

Comment: In this case, the code is actually a data object being generated from a database query.  It can't simply be entered in by hand, because its exact value isn't known when the code is written, and can in fact change every time the Python file is run. EDIT: Whoops, didn't see *your* edit.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not javascript, that's a python replacement in the python script.